# How to display the numbers of this exercise in ascending order in java?

Tags: java

I got this exercise where i need to build a program in java that creates a 1-dimensional table where 10 integers will be stored, which will be read from the keyboard. At the end the program will display all the integers that are larger than average. (As you can see i've done this). But i need to display the numbers that are larger than average in ascending order. So there should be another instruction in the end, please help  I should say that im a beginner in java though. shuma=sum, mesatarja=average tabela = array though

[please see it and help me solve this :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kgpD.jpg)

Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

```
    int [] tabela = new int [10];
    
    System.out.print("Ju lutem jepni 10 nr te plote: ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i<tabela.length; i++) {
        tabela[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    
    System.out.println("Tabela = " + Arrays.toString(tabela));

    int shuma = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < tabela.length; i++)
    shuma = shuma + tabela[i];
    
    double mesatarja = shuma*1.0/tabela.length;
    
    System.out.println("Mesatarja e numrave eshte: " + mesatarja);
    
    System.out.print("Numrat me te medhenj se mesatarja jane: ");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < tabela.length; i++) {
        if (tabela[i] > mesatarja) {
        System.out.print(tabela[i] + ", ");
        }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. May I kindly suggest to take a programming tutorial on programming in java first? This is rally basic stuff. StackOverflow is for HARD coding problems, not for doing the homework for you.

Comment: I would also add that you should post your actual code and not a screenshot of it.

Comment: I also posted the code, sorry.

Comment: @StarShine i've seen some, this is not the best way to say welcome to a beginner though but thanks:')

Comment: @DionisCura No hard feelings intended. It's totally fine and normal to be a beginner, but it's also totally fine and normal to read and try out code from a textbook first before firing questions at the world. There are plenty of on-line coding tools where you can freely experiment in the language of your choice: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Answer (score 1):

The simplest idea that comes to mind is to sort the array. You should use any sort algorithm after filling your array.
Example using "buble sort":

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabela.length-1; i++) 
    for (int j = 0; j < tabela.length-i-1; j++) 
        if (tabela[j] > tabela[j+1]) 
           { 
             int temp = tabela[j]; 
             tabela[j] = tabela[j+1]; 
             tabela[j+1] = temp; 
           }
```

[Here](https://stackabuse.com/sorting-algorithms-in-java/) you can find an explanation of the algorithms and their examples.

Comment: Thank you, how can i display it with System.out.print then? Sorry, i'm a beginner.

Comment: You just can insert my code into yours before System.out.println("Tabela = " + Arrays.toString(tabela));
After sorting your array will contain all your nums (inputed) but already in ascending order. Therefore, you will get the desired result using the output method you described (from 30 to 35 lines according to your screenshot)

Comment: I tried it but that displays all the array in ascending order, i want only the tabela [i] elements on the ascending order because i dont want all the numbers of the array but only the elements that are larger than the avarage. Sorry for disturbing you though, hope you can help me.

Comment: No problem, insert my code below System.out.println("Tabela = " + Arrays.toString(tabela));

Comment: I displayed all of the array on the ascending order first, then i found the average and the elements that are larger than that. Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, there is [java.util.Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D))

Comment: @user yeah... I forgot about this